# Inspect UI elements in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex3, flexbuilder

Is there any tool available for Flex applications that acts similar to Web Developer or Firebug toolbar to inspect UI elements?

Basically in a complex hierarchy of UI controls allowing you to browse the elements and see properties such as x and y coordinates, width, height, id.

I'm interested in tools that would allow you to do this at runtime, since most of the properties are dynamic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also try [FlexSpy](http://code.google.com/p/fxspy/). Unlike De MonsterDebugger (which looks good, too), you don't need to install AIR. It doesn't do as much, but certainly allows you to view properties of components in real-time (and to change some of them). It's easy to use:

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
  ...
  <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
      import com.flexspy.FlexSpy;
    ]]>
  </mx:Script>
  ...
  <mx:Button id="btnFlexSpy" label="FlexSpy" click="FlexSpy.show()" />
  ...
</mx:Application>
```

It looks like this:

[alt text http://coderpeon.ovh.org/wp-content/110507-0844-flexspy111.png](http://coderpeon.ovh.org/wp-content/110507-0844-flexspy111.png)

Answer (score 3):

I have heard good things about "[Kap Inspect](http://lab.kapit.fr/display/kapinspect/Kap+Inspect)" but I have not used it personally.  They have a demo on their site.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at http://www.demonsterdebugger.com/

you will have to add some extra code but it is easy to do and gives you a wealth of information. works with Flex, AIR and Flash.